# PHP array in $_SESSION - weird result

Tags: php

can anyone explain this to me?:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pack'])){
   if (is_array($_SESSION['pack'])){
      foreach ($_SESSION['pack'] as $pack){
         //code
      }
   }
}
```

i get:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

and if i do

```
die(var_dump($_SESSION['pack']));
```

i get

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "16" }
```

i'm really going bonkers with this one, i need it ready for tonight and i'm stuck with this...

Thanks

Comment: did u try to run in for loop ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you have register_globals enabled, `$_SESSION['pack']` will be the same as `$pack`. That might produce the wired results. Either make sure register_globals is disabled, or rename `$pack` to something else.

Comment: @fab You might want to make your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the line

```
foreach ($_SESSION['pack'] as $pack){...
```

If you have [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) enabled, `$_SESSION['pack']` will be the same as `$pack`. That might produce the weird results. Either make sure register_globals is disabled, or rename `$pack` to something else.